# populating Hive table from file yields far too many rows

Tags: sql, hive

I am creating a Hive table from a file with 8k rows, but the table created has 78k rows.  The command line is the following:

`bin/hive_executable < my_script.hql`

my_script.hql:

```
create table my_table(k1 t1, k2 t2....);
load data local inpath 'path/to/table_file.txt' INTO TABLE my_table;
```

table_file.txt:
`v1 v2 v3...`

I've tried both space and tab delimited fields, and explicitly declaring the structure in the create table statement. When I use example code to create a table from $HIVE_HOME/example/file/kv1.txt, the table and file both have 500 lines / rows.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strip text fields of all newline characters.